# Nested Group By type operation in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Say my table looks like this:

[image]

Now I can get a complete sum for a, b by a simple Group By, but is it possible to get the above nested group-by type output with a single optimized query?

Workaround which I'm using right now is I retrieve all records for Cat1=a, then apply a group by on Cat2. But since Cat1 are many in number (a,b,c,d...etc) this becomes way too many queries.

What's would you suggest?

Comment: SELECT cat1, SUM(CASE WHEN cat2='x' THEN val END) forx, SUM(CASE...) fory GROUP BY cat1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select cat1, 
       sum(case when cat2='x' then val end) as sumValForX,
       sum(case when cat2='y' then val end) as sumValForY
from your_table
group by cat1
```

#### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be73d/1)

Comment: This wouldn't work, where are we mentioning that we need the column 'val' to sum?